# Find out who deleted records from my PostgreSql table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called "users" which is an administrative table for the applicaiton users.

I need to find out who deleted records from this table.

As my application is using a single DB user, and the DB is running on Linux, getting the ip address of the Linux server and the name of the DB user, is not enough.

I need something like the ip address of the pc of the person who connected the DB, or something of the sort.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The database only knows the database client. Everything else must be logged by your application.

Answer (score 0):

In the unlikely event you have `log_statements` cranked up to "mod" or "all" and you have "%h" in your `log_line_prefix` and that the user connected directly to the database rather than through an app server, then you could find out the IP address through your log files.  More likely you would have to go through the app server's log files, if you keep them detailed enough.